# How to make Prettier ignore markdown comments for newlines

Tags: markdown, prettier, prettier-vscode

I have a markdown file with:

```
<!-- omit in toc -->
## Title name
```

but when I format it with Prettier, it will automatically add a newline:

```
<!-- omit in toc -->

## Title name
```

Is there any way to stop Prettier from doing this will keeping its other formatting functionalities? Because I like using Prettier to break up large text blocks into 80 character width lines.

If not, are there any vscode formatters that will just break up lines into 80 character width lines without adding newlines?